# Execute a RESTAPI request from Powershell using the credentials of the user logged into the windows machine(AD Credential's)

Tags: rest, active-directory, single-sign-on, powershell-4.0

I want to login/communicate to a remote system using RESTAPI and I want to use the same AD credentials of the user firing the script from a windows machine.
Example:-
I am logged into a Windows server with the credentials "Domain\User" with password "password" and want to login using the same credentials to login to a remote system without entering the username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using WebClient class:

```
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$reply = $webClient.DownloadString("http://google.com")
$reply
```

The main thing here is to set `UseDefaultCredentials` property of `WebClient` to `true`.
Method `DownloadString` is just an example of how to use `WebClient`. There are plenty of other methods which you can use depending on your REST endpoint. You can find full list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks ,Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: So how do we use this to pass the credentials.I was previously using this to manually pass the credentials.
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -Credential $credentials -method Get

Comment: You do not need to - by specifying UseDefaultCredentials you tell WebClient to use current user's credentials.